# Delete ticks between breaks in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to create a line graph with irregular break intervals on the x-axis. When I define the breaks as in the code example, I get additional unlabeled breaks, which always seem to be exactly in the middle of two defined breaks and thus are unregular too (see image in link).

```
test_frame <- data.frame("v1"=1:3,"v2"=3:1)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = test_frame, aes(x=v1, y=v2, group=1))+geom_line()+
scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(2.74,2.43,1.19))
```

Graph with additional breaks:

[image: Graph with additional breaks]

Is there any way to get rid of these vertical lines, so that there are only lines at the defined break position? I'd be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Those are "minor breaks".  I usually remove them as shown in the answer.  If I only want to remove them from the `x` axis I use `theme(panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank() )`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `minor_breaks = NULL`:

```
scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(2.74,2.43,1.19), minor_breaks = NULL)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
ggplot(data = test_frame, aes(x = v1, y = v2, group = 1)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(2.74, 2.43, 1.19)) +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) # or panel.grid.minor.x to keep horizontal lines
```

[image]